# Multiple left mouse click causes Windows 7 OS to hang

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, mouse, freeze

I've this strange problem for sometime on my Fujitsu Windows 7 laptop 64 bit.  If I left double click my USB mouse too many times or too rapidly (I'm not sure which), my OS will hang completely, the screen freezes (no blue screen), even ctrl-alt-del don't work.  If I'm playing music on my laptop speakers, there will also be a loud "DIZZZZZZZ" constant sound.  Only a hard reset by pressing the laptop power button for a few seconds will reboot the OS.

I've changed mouse previously but this problem still remains.  Under device manager, the mouse section says "HID compliant mouse", version 6.1.7600.16385.  Update driver says I've got the latest driver installed.

Another thing which I've observed previously but can't confirm is that shaking the USB cable where it connects to the laptop may also cause a hang.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Sounds like a USB faulty. Have you tried another port? If you are on a laptop do you get the same issue if you rapidly click the built in mouse?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams  Thanks. My mouse is connected to a USB hub. I read a suggestion posted elsewhere to disable "Enable pointer precision" under Device manager->Mouse setup. Try that now. By the way, I think it's something to do with the USB port as I suspect that connecting USB device to another port (not the one the USB hub uses) can also cause a freeze if the connection is disturbed - I can't totally confirm this. Could this problem be related to the USB controller?

Comment: If you are having issues on all your USB ports it could very well be the controller. If it's a hardware issue there isn't anything you can do about it. A good place to start would be to download and reinstall USB drivers from your manufacturer website.